# Woocommerce sidebar not in place

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

[image]

This is the site I'm developing in woocommerce. The sidebar is not showing on the right side of category page only on the categories page. On the product page its showing fine.

The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive.

Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide any code to help with solving your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem bro is on your div element structure. Try to sort the opening and closing of every div's involve on your template. header to header, content to content, sidebar to sidebar, footer to footer div element.

Comment: I know but with woocommerce I don't know where its coming from and removing or adding divs is not helping. Thanks for the help mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Woocommerce theme, custom build, or other theme?

I would advise checking that the content wrappers are still the same as on other pages. Woocommerce wants to use its own wrapper div's.
for example. On most of your pages you might have wrappers like:

```
<div id="primary">
     <!-- ... Main content of your site -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Woocommerce might be overriding this to:

```
<div id="container"><div id="content" role="main">
```

To fix this copy `wrapper-start.php` and `wrapper-end.php` to  `yourtheme/woocommerce/global/` then fix the open and close divs in the respective files.

Also you could look at `loop-start.php` and `loop-end.php` in `/loop/`

Or you could try unhooking the wrappers and adding in your own:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'add_content_inner_wrapp', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'close_content_inner_wrap', 10, 1 );
function add_content_inner_wrapp(){
?>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content-inner">
<?php   
}
function close_content_inner_wrap(){
?>
        </div><!-- #content-inner-->
    </div><!-- #container-->
<?php   
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help joe. I tried but couldn't solve the issue. Here are the two links if you can inspect the code.

http://supersonicit.com.au/ezaango/categories/

http://supersonicit.com.au/ezaango/product-category/baby-children/

I have inspected the code and what I can see is body classes are different. I also tried making same but no luck :(